# What is the need for immutable/persistent data structures in erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, immutability

Each Erlang process maintains its own private address space. All communication happens via copying without sharing *(except big binaries)*. If each process is processing one message at a time with no concurrent access over its objects, I don't see why do we need immutable/[persistent data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure).

Comment: Can you give some examples of what Erlang data structures you have in mind when you talk about  'persistent data structures'?

Comment: For scala/akka, persistent only needed when a actor crash & needed to be restart, the actor needs the persistent to setup its data when recover, maybe erlang similar? BTW, you may need to remove akka tag?

Comment: @lagom I am not talking about persisting it to database. Its related to immutable datastructures in fp languages.

Comment: @aronisstav For example the singly linked list. Its a persistent data structure, if you only add elements to the head.

Comment: @t0il3ts0ap Would you also use 'immutable' to describe the same idea as you're describing by 'persistent'?

Comment: Erlang asks the opposite question to the one you ask: is there a particular need for mutable data structures, given its use cases? And answers "no".

Comment: @aronisstav Yes. Persistent data structures are upgrades of immutable data structures. They offer immutability with much better performance.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Definetely, mutable structures solves lot of problems ( eg, in arrays you can access any element in O(1)). From my eyes, it looks erlang only needs immutable data structures when sharing big binaries.

Comment: For example, when you manipulate trees, or lists, you can reuse complete branches or lists queues without particular caution since you know that they will nether change. At the beginning I was also annoyed by the lack of efficient arrays, now I consider that they are rather poor data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed the case that in Erlang immutability does not solve any "shared state" problems, as immutable data are "process local".

From the *functional programming language* perspective, however, immutability offers a number of benefits, summarized adequately in [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-immutability-important-in-functional-programming):

> The simplest definition of functional programming is that it’s a programming
>   paradigm where you are transforming immutable data with functions.
>
> The definition uses functions in the mathematical sense, where it’s
>   something that takes an input, and produces an output.
>
> OO + mutability tends to violate that definition because when you want
>   to change a piece of data it generally will not return the output, it
>   will likely return void or unit, and that when you call a method on
>   the object the object itself isn’t input for the function.
>
> As far as what advantages the paradigm has, composability, thread
>   safety, being able to track what went wrong where better, the ability
>   to sort of separate the data from the actual computation on it being
>   done, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Erlang was initially implemented in Prolog, which doesn't really use mutable data structures either (though some dialects do). So it started off without them. This makes runtime implementation simpler and faster (garbage collection in particular).

So adding mutable data structures would require a lot of effort, could introduce bugs, and Erlang programmers are nearly by definition at least willing to live without them.

Many actually consider their absence to be a positive good: less concern about object identity, no need for defensive copying because you don't know whether some other piece of code is going to modify the data you passed (or might be changed later to modify it), etc.

This absence does mean that Erlang is pretty unusable in some domains (e.g. high performance scientific computing), at least as the main language. But again, this means that nobody in these domains is going to use Erlang in the first place and so there's no particular incentive to make it usable at the cost of making existing users unhappy.

I remember seeing a mailing list post by Joe Armstrong quite a long time ago (which I couldn't find with a quick search now) saying that he initially planned to add mutable variables when he'd need them... except he never quite did, and performance was good enough for everything he was using Erlang for.

Answer (score 0):

how would this work?

```
factorial(1) -> 1;
factorial(X) ->
    X*factorial(X-1).
```

if you run factorial(4), a single process will be running the same function. Each time the function will have it's own value of X, if the value of X was in the scope of the process and not the function recursive functions wouldn't work. So first we need to understand scope. If you want to say that you don't see why data needs to be immutable within the scope of a single function/block you would have a point, but it would be a headache to think about where data is immutable and where it isn't.

Comment: Can you answer in terms of multiple processes, where there is need for immutable/persistent data structures.